# SQL Server agent job recreated

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-job

I stuck in a issue from last 6 months. I had a SQL Servre job `SALES lOAD` which is created with a T-SQL script. This job is being recreated every month automatically. How we know which job affected or recreated my `SALES lOAD` load every month. I checked each and every job but no job is affecting this job

Answer (score 0):

You may check if there is any process scheduled to run every month (BAT file,Task scheduler job, etc...)

Comment: yes , one of the Step has BAT file but it is used to fetch raw data from particular directory.

Comment: What i meant is check for the anything on you local machine which is executing T-SQL script to recreate SQL Agent job. Anything inside job won't affecting in your case.

Comment: can we know this from sql server log

Comment: Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools\    Check for event viewer and task scheduler to make sure there isn't any job running or scheduled for you SQL Agent job.

Comment: Hi Mithesh, Thanks for your Cooperation, I checked Task scheduler and Event log on my local as suggested by you but no job scheduled or event which interfere my existing job. Can you please suggest some other aspect of this

Comment: Can anybody please help on the above issue